# How to display part of a string underlined to an asp.net Label control?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have an asp Label control used for displaying error messages to the user.  My client
would like certain words in these messages to be underlined.  How would this be accomplished?

Thank you,
James

Comment: Do you have static text or its changing all the time(like populating from database)?

Comment: It is static, but I currently have three possible messages that will be sent in the same control based on conditions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simpler version of David Andres's solution :

```
Label.Text = "this is an <u>underlined expression</u>";
```

Comment: Actually, this is the one I used... Easy!  Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify this applies to ASP and System.Web.UI.WebControls, while the standard .NET label simply uses "&" for underlining.

Answer (score 2):

Though a bit hacky, you can assign HTML markup to the Label's Text property.  Something like this should suffice:

```
Label.Text = "this is an <span class='underlineIt'>underlined expression</span>";
```

The would assign class `underlineIt` to the words "underlined expression."  Within the underlineIt CSS class, you can set the rule `text-decoration: underline`.

Comment: This sounds like it could work, I will give it a try.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I total misunderstood the question blah.

Embed the HTML into the label's text property.

Comment: I can't underline the whole string of text, only certain words are to be underlined.

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a literal control are not html encoded so you could swap out the label control then insert  tags around the words you want underlined.

```
<asp:Literal ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text='my <u>underlined</u> text' />
```

Comment: I would use <span class='underlineIt'>underlined expression</span> to wrap the words as did David Andres. I think however that asp might html encode the labels text by default not giving you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way and sample code.

```
<asp:Label ID="Label88" runat="server" Font-Underline="true" Font-Bold="true" Text="RESULT"></asp:Label>
```